# why does $_GET['name'] is Nothing, when i navigate to http://example.com/test.php?&lt;&lt;&lt;Apple&gt;&gt;&gt;

Tags: php, get, global

I have a website which gets variables with `GET` method (assume it replies with properties like `http://example.com/test.php?id=Apple` will return properties of Apple), and it uses `$_GET['id']` Global variable in php to retrieve requested id.

Problem is whenever I navigate to that site

```
http://example.com/test.php?id=&amp;lt;&amp;lt;&amp;lt;Apple&amp;gt;&amp;gt;&amp;gt;
```

it just doesnt work, because `$GET['id']` is empty. Why ?

I have to use `GET`, because I will be sharing it with customers and they can modify it to whatever they want. If I cannot use `GET`, what are my options ?

php file:

test.php

> echo $_GET['id'];

Comment: updated as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_GET['id'] is empty because each time you are putting & character is like you are adding another parameter to the url, so if you print_r($_GET) you'll see something like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [lt;] => 
    [lt;Apple] => 
    [gt;] => 
)
```

You can try substringing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.
In this case, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` should be something like `id=<<<Apple>>>`, so you can just `echo substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],3)`.

Comment: It Worked like a charm!  Thanks for your calm reply without arrogance. <3; should i use $_SERVER global for GET methods always? and by using this method, does it mean, i cannot append more variables with &password= ?

Comment: using $_SERVER is just a little hack, you can always play with substrings and regex to get multiple params with $_SERVER but yo should try to avoid characters like & or = ... in the url